# Is it possible to set the decimals on a Number field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, pnp-js-core

I'm trying to update number fields to hold only 1 decimal place but I can't seem to do this through REST.

I tried Pnp Js but it's not working, there's no error, it just doesn't update:

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Risks").fields.getByInternalNameOrTitle('ImpactCost').update({
    DisplayFormat: 4
}, 'SP.FieldNumber')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to update number field with decimal point using REST API. Below is my rest code. should help.

```
function updateListItem() {          
            var formdigestValue = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
            var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
            var updateMetadata = { __metadata: { 'type': "SP.Data.TestlistListItem" }, 'numberfld': 10.888 };          
            $.ajax
            ({
                url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Testlist')/items(1)",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(updateMetadata),
                headers:
                {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",                    
                    "X-RequestDigest": formdigestValue,
                    "IF-MATCH": "*",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
                },

                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    console.log("number updated");                    
                },
                error: function (data,xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log("Error While Updating: " + data.responseJSON.error);                        
                }
            });

        }
```

Change type attribute (`SP.Data.TestlistListItem`) in metadata with your list category term & change column name(`numberfld`).

**NOTE:** In case, If you are trying to update number as decimal point preceding with zeros (10.00) then field will automatically round it as whole number(10).